# Windows 7 numlock issues with RDP causes machine to go crazy

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

After going through a few RDP sessions to Windows XP machines, when I come back to my local machine it appears some setting has been tripped so every key I type is registered as one of the function/alt keys plus the key I type, causing Windows to open and close windows randomly and other erratic behavior.  Pressing the Windows key and numlock returns everything to normal.  What causes this?

I have experienced this on multiple Windows 7 machines, but never in Windows Vista or Windows XP.

Comment: Laptop or desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Tell me this - did you use Win Key + L to lock either system while in the RDP session? If so, then I've hit this bug before while working on my VDI via PCoIP. The only solution I've found is to reboot.